# How does the "tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/ir/tf_generated_ops.td" file generated?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there any script in TF to generate the contents in "tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/ir/tf_generated_ops.td" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is such a script but not in open-source: the script is more used to bootstrap, it has some rough edges and isn't complete, and as such we didn't open source it. We'd prefer to have one that is more complete/doesn't surprise users :).

If a "this only bootstraps creating the definition of an op" tool would be useful, we can look into cleaning that up and open-sourcing part of it.

Comment: Thank you a lot. And I think such a tool would be useful. Looking foward to the open source of it.